# Minus sign in RTL textbox

Tags: html, css

How can I display negative numbers in right to left textbox, with the minus on the left of the number?

Current state: 1-
Desired state: -1

Comment: How are you making it right-to-left ... with CSS direction:rtl?

Comment: @SirCrispalot, Yes **sir**... ;-)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the markup that is produced?

Comment: @SirCrispalot, It's a simple textbox with direction:rtl on the entire <body>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On your textbox you just need to reset the `direction`, and align the text to the right:

```css
BODY {
  direction: rtl;
}

#test {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.<br />

  <input type="text" id="test" value="-109309" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why won't I change all the textboxes and labels to the #myInput style? What is the difference between direction rtl then text-align: right?

Comment: `#myInput` was just for an example. You'd need to change the CSS selector to match whatever your code requires. As for the difference, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430148/differences-between-direction-and-text-align-in-css

Comment: Yes I read this question, loved that questioner... **=)**  Thanks!

Comment: LOL - only just noticed that was your question too!

Answer (score 8):

This is a general issue with RTL/LTR when it comes to contexts in UI.

Short answer: The best approach is to dedicate numerical inputs and string inputs to separate textboxes. Numbers for most RTL languages (not all, beware!) are LTR, and strings are RTL, and splitting the context allows you to define your inputs properly.

Example -

```html
Place: <input type="text" dir="rtl" />
Temperature: <input type="number" dir="ltr" />
```

Note that W3C recommends setting the language in the html markup rather than the CSS, which is also better for accessibility and screen readers. Adding a lang="" attribute is also recommended, if possible.

There are several good reasons to split textboxes for strings and numbers separately when possible, especially for RTL/LTR:

- This is usually a good UX decision, because it makes it clear to your user what they are expected to type.
- You get a clear distinction in your code (or whatever analyzes the form fields) about what is a string and what is a numberical input, for whatever calculations or display concerns.
- When you display the results, you can make sure the number and text are displayed correctly (using `<span dir="ltr">...</span>` or `dir="rtl"` when relevant)
- Defining an input as numerical allows mobile devices to load the number pad rather than the full keyboard, which is a bonus for UX.

I know this question is several years old, but I hope this can help with the new considerations (and some technology updates since then, especially mobile) to anyone interested in supporting RTL or mixed directions in their forms.